# Creating a python script printing the results of a ping into a rotating log

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I'm trying to create a script in python which continuously pings a specific host and prints the result of that into a daily rotating log file.
The logs of the last 30 days should be kept, everything older should be deleted.
I have absolutely no expierience using python.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I managed to create a script printing out the results of a ping into a file
`command = os.system('ping 127.0.0.1 > new.txt')`
and I managed to create a daily rotating scriptbut I really can't manage to combine those two.

Comment: To code in Python please consider studying Python. There are plenty of free courses in the wild, as an example have a look at:

https://www.learnpython.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard python logging module:

Below it's a code example using "TimedRotatingFileHandler" from the logging package. Basically we create a logging handler that will log in a file for 30 days, then replace it with a new file. Every time that we use the log method the logs automatically goes in that file.
For the pinging part we're using the subprocess package and run the ping command in the background to capture it's output.

```
import logging
import time
import subprocess

from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler


def ping_host(path, hostname, ping_delay=20):
    """"""
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path,
                                       when="d",
                                       interval=30,
                                       backupCount=1)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    while True:
        response = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/ping", "-c1", "-w100", 
hostname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
        logger.info("Ping at {0}, result: {1}".format(time.time(), 
response))
        time.sleep(ping_delay)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hostname = "google.com"
    log_file = "timed_test.log"
    ping_host(log_file, hostname)
```

When you define the constructor "TimedRotatingFileHandler" you can pass parameters like:

- (path) log file path with name
- (when) interval type here we have "d" which means "day", other possible values are "m", "s", "h"
- (interval) the actual interval as a integer, we have defined 30 days
- (backupCount) how many copies of the logs are there, if more then 1 are specified more log files will be kept

If you like to test it in real time replace "d" with "s" (second)

The script needs to be kept running to do it's work.

You could run it in background in the linux shell:

```
nohup python3 your_file.py &
```